# Change font / window size for the Visual Studio terminal

Tags: visual-studio-2015

It looks like the settings for the command window / terminal should take the defaults I've already applied to the regular command window but it doesn't seem to change anything.

cmd -> the window remembers font / window size changes

visual studio -> the default settings do not apply and I can't find any other option to change it.

Anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with the below

If you are opening your command prompt in windows using the Windows 10 search box it will run a shortcut called "Command Prompt" (You can right click on it and open file location) This appears to have it's own font size and display options within it's properties.

Visual studio appears to run the cmd.exe directly from the system32 folder, not the windows shortcut.

If you open cmd.exe directly and makes changes to it's properties they will be reflected in Visual Studio. You just need to ensure that when you open the command prompt in windows you do so by running cmd.exe directly, not the command prompt shortcut.

Alternatively get Visual Studio to use the shortcut - but I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: You can't change the font and appearances in the cmd.exe or PowerShell executable files. The only solution I found is to go on the menu "Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors"  and select the Terminal in the "Show settings for" dropdown and then change the font and size as you wish.